Is lfence needed for spectre v1 mitigation in case WB memory type?
as far as i know, LFENCE is LoadLoad barrier hence its useless in case of WB memory type.
I tried to look over articles that explains how to mitigate spectre v1, and i saw they suggests to use lfence before the critical code, i dont understand why we need LFENCE for WB memory type.
Does x86-SSE-instructions have an automatic release-acquire order?
Does the Intel Memory Model make SFENCE and LFENCE redundant?
As i understand, for memory type WB lfence is redundant because its just loadload barrier, do we still need lfence to mitigate spectre in case of WB memory?

LoadLoad reordering doesn't happen on x86 AFAIK, also spectre v1 is about branch target mispeculation, not memory reordering (lfence is used to stop executing later instruction speculatively)

looking on lfence description, its all about loadload barrier and not barrier of any instructions, if that its only effect, i still dont understand why we need it. as i understand, it works because lfence say we must wait for previous load and not speculative guess it, but isnt it true for any load that xomes after first load? or maybe i dont understand the attack well and there are cases we have only one load( the speculative load of the spectre attack) and we dont have other load in order to exploit the attack and thats why we need lfence?

Look at Intel's documentation for lfence (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lfence) - LFENCE does not execute until all prior instructions have completed locally, and no later instruction begins execution until LFENCE completes - this part is about instruction execution, not memory ordering.  LFENCE is indeed useless for memory ordering on WB memory, but not for execution ordering.  e.g. with rdtsc for microbenchmarking, and more recently for Spectre mitigation.  See also Understanding the impact of lfence on a loop with two long dependency chains

@PeterCordes thanks! so what prevent the branch speculation to continue is the statment "have completed locally"?

Yes.  That means "retired from the ROB (reorder buffer)".
